# how do I split a string on the nth delimiter?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

For every line in my file, I want to print everything on that line before the 4th dash.

Input:

```
TCGA-HC-8216-10A-11D-A323-01
TCGA-J4-8200-10A-11D-A323-01
TCGA-EJ-A65E-10A-11D-A323-01
```

and I want to split each line on the fourth dash "-"

Output:

```
TCGA-HC-8216-10A
TCGA-J4-8200-10A
TCGA-EJ-A65E-10A
```

I know I can split on every dash like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IN="TCGA-HC-8216-01A-11D-A323-01
TCGA-J4-8200-10A-11D-A323-01
TCGA-EJ-A65E-10A-11D-A323-01"

arr=$(echo $IN | tr "-" "\n")

for x in $arr
do
 echo "> [$x]"
done
```

but this splits and prints each part of the string between every dash.

Comment: Look at the `cut` command and/or `awk`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `cut`

```
cut -d- -f1-4 <<'EOF'
TCGA-HC-8216-01A-11D-A323-01
TCGA-J4-8200-10A-11D-A323-01
TCGA-EJ-A65E-10A-11D-A323-01
EOF
```

You are cutting your input on `-d` (delimiter) of `-` and returning `-f` (fields) `1-4`, one through four.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

IN="TCGA-HC-8216-01A-11D-A323-01
TCGA-J4-8200-10A-11D-A323-01
TCGA-EJ-A65E-10A-11D-A323-01"

arr=$(echo "$IN" | cut -d '-' -f1-4)

echo "$arr"
```

Prints:

```
TCGA-HC-8216-01A
TCGA-J4-8200-10A
TCGA-EJ-A65E-10A
```

Answer (score 0):

Using grep with ERE:

```
arr=$(echo "$IN" | grep -oE "^([^-]*-){3}[^-]*")
```

With BRE:

```
arr=$(echo "$IN" | grep -o "^\([^-]*-\)\{3\}[^-]*")
```

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
IN="TCGA-HC-8216-01A-11D-A323-01
TCGA-J4-8200-10A-11D-A323-01
TCGA-EJ-A65E-10A-11D-A323-01"

arr=$(echo "$IN" | grep -oE "^([^-]*-){3}[^-]*")

for x in $arr
do
 echo "> [$x]"
done
```

Output:

```
> [TCGA-HC-8216-01A]
> [TCGA-J4-8200-10A]
> [TCGA-EJ-A65E-10A]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pure bash and pattern matching:

```
#!/bin/bash    
IN="TCGA-HC-8216-01A-11D-A323-01
TCGA-J4-8200-10A-11D-A323-01
TCGA-EJ-A65E-10A-11D-A323-01"

re='([^-]+-){3}[^-]+'

for line in $IN
do

    if [[ $line =~ $re ]]; then
        trunc=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
    fi
    echo "$trunc"
done
```

Output:

```
TCGA-HC-8216-01A
TCGA-J4-8200-10A
TCGA-EJ-A65E-10A
```